# Search multiple columns in sqlite SELECT FROM

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this code to search for Column A. What modification should I make if I want to search Column A and Column B simultaneously?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ColumnA + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ColumnA + " LIMIT 100";
```

I've tried this but it's not work:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ColumnA + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ColumnA + " LIMIT 100 OR SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ColumnB + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ColumnB + " LIMIT 100";
```

Any mistake I made?

Answer (score 2):

You can use OR to connect two expressions.
However, both must be complete expressions:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ColA LIKE ? OR ColB LIKE ? ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for UNION instead of OR?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make two differrent query. And combine results by `union` keyword.

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where columnA like ? order by columnA limit 100
union
select * from TABLE_NAME where columnB like ? order by columnA limit 100
```

Comment: **UNION ALL** includes the eventual duplicates. **UNION** doesn't.

Comment: How I should modify my string sql code to include union? I've tried `string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
       " WHERE " + columnA + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + columnA + " LIMIT 100" + "UNION ALL" +
    "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
    " WHERE " + columnB + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + columnA + " LIMIT 100";` but it's not work.

Comment: I am getting error `ORDER BY clause should come after UNION ALL not before`

Answer (score 0):

To the OP:

In your answer, the filtering must be the `OR` of each field individually against the `LIKE ?`.

So the line should be `String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( " + ColumnA + " LIKE ?) OR (" + ColumnB + " LIKE ?) ORDER BY " + ColumnA + " LIMIT 100";`